# Hibernate Query for ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

A bit of disclaimer:

- I am at beginner level in Java
- I am beginner level at hibernate

Ok, since we have got that out of the way, my question is the following:

My EmailAddressModel has the below mapping to EmailAddressTag

```
private String id;
@Column(unique = true)
private String emailAddressName;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<EmailAddressTag> emailAddressTags = new HashSet<EmailAddressTag>();
```

and my EmailAddressTag is:

```
private String id;    
@Column(unique = true)
private String emailAddressTags;
```

Sample data set:

```
id: 1
emailAddressName: abc@gmail.com
tags (id=1,emailAddressTags=tag1)
```

How can I construct a query to fetch an Email address knowing the tag (the entire object) using HQL.
Something like

```
select * from EmailAddressTable where EmailAddressTable.Tag = 'tag1'
```

I have tried:

```
Set<EmailAddressTag> listOfTags = new HashSet<EmailAddressTag>();
listOfTags.add(tagToSearch);
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM EmailAddressTable item WHERE item.Tag IN (:tags)");
query.setParameterList("tags", listOfTags)
```

But, the error (java error) I have if use setParameterList is

> Cannot cast ...EmailAddressTag to java.util.Collection

And the error (hibernate error) I have if use setParameter is

> malformed numeric constant: .

Any help I will truly appreciate. Really lost here.

Comment: What is the `EmailAddressTable`? How did you name it?

Comment: EmailAddress. But does it affect? I am able to do CRUD on it without any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer.
Its as follows.

operator is AND or OR

```
String hql = String.format("FROM %s obj where 1=1 ",c.getSimpleName());
for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
    hql += " "+operator+" :collection" + i + " = some elements(obj.emailAddressTags)";
}

Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
    query.setParameter("collection" + i, tempList.get(i));
}
list = query.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix the compiler error, if you actually use a collection for the `listOfTags` variable. You did not show that part of the code, but it could look something like this:

```
Set<EmailAddressTag> listOfTags = new HashSet<EmailAddressTag>();
listOfTags.add(tagToSearchFor);
...
query.setParameterList("tags", listOfTags);
```

If you want use `setParameter()` instead, you should be able to fix the hibernate error, if you change your query condition to only check for a single tag:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM EmailAddressTable item WHERE item.Tag = :tag");
query.setParameter("tag", tagToSearchFor)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think there is a bit of misunderstanding. Check my editted question (for your first part). 2nd part, I have a use case where I have to pass in a list instead of one by one